# "swagger-codegen" and "openapi-generator" unintentionally convert a datetime without a time zone to a datetime with UTC time zone

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restful, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I wrote a parameter that "type:" is "string" and "example:" is a text datetime without time zone like "2021-09-01 00:00:00".

but on the UI that was generated by swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.27.jar or openapi-generator-cli-5.2.1.jar,
the parameter format is ISO 8601 format with UTC timzone like "2021-09-01T00:00:00Z"

I don't want to convert datetime format.
I want to show without time zone style.
How do I write spec file?

test.yml

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: test
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /test/{dateTime}/:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: "dateTime"
          in: "path"
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            example: "2021-09-01 00:00:00"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  dateTime2:
                    type: string
                    example: "2021-09-01 00:00:00"
```

then

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.27.jar generate -i test.yaml -l python-flask -o test-flask
cd test-flask
python -m swagger_server
```

or

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-5.2.1.jar generate -i test.yaml -g python-flask -o test-flask
cd test-flask
python -m openapi_server
```

then open "http://localhost:8080/ui/#/default/test_date_time_get"

[image]